# Replace datetime characters in a string

Tags: python, string, date, replace

Consider the following example `str` of dates:

`'20180101,20180102,20180103,20180104,20180105,20180106,20180107,20180108,20180109,20180110,20180111,20180112,20180113,20180114,20180115,20180116,20180117,20180118,20180119,20180120,20180121,20180122,20180123,20180124,20180125,20180126,20180127,20180128,20180129,20180130,20180131,20180201,20180202,20180203,20180204,20180205,20180206,20180207,20180208'`.

Using `.replace('2018','2018-')`, or `re.sub('2018', '2018-', foo_string)` from the module `re`, a date changes to `2018-0101`. However, I'd like to insert a hyphen for a range of dates. I have tried the following `re.sub('{}'.format(range(2018,2019)), '2018-', foo_string)` to no avail. The string is returned without any changes. For reference the years I'd like to range over for the hyphen are 1981 to 2018.

Additionally, I'm unsure of a way to insert a hyphen between the month and dates in a clean way. Help along these directions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want `20180101` to be `2018-01-01`?

Comment: @heemayl Yes, all dates are in this format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that using `datetime` will be more pythonic,

```
from datetime import datetime

date_list = '20180101,20180102,20180103,20180104,20180105,20180106,20180107,20180108'

def new_date_format(old_format_str):
    date_format = datetime.strptime(old_format_str, '%Y%m%d')
    new_format = date_format.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    return new_format

for date_str in date_list.split(","):
    print(new_date_format(date_str))
```

This will produce the following output:

```
2018-01-01
2018-01-02
2018-01-03
2018-01-04
2018-01-05
2018-01-06
2018-01-07
2018-01-08
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
def insert_hyphen(stri):
    return ",".join([date[:4]+"-"+date[4:] for date in stri.split(',')])
```

if you want double hyphens then do

```
def insert_hyphen(stri):
    return ",".join([date[:4]+"-"+date[4:6]+"-"+date[6:] for date in stri.split(',')])
```

Comment: Works better if you combine KGSH's answer with yours, i.e., `def insert_hyphen(stri):
    return ",".join([date[:4:] + '-' + date[4:6:] + '-' + date[6::] for date in stri.split(',')])`

Answer (score 1):

If your list consists of dates, why not store your list *as* dates?

Python has a `datetime` module which facilitates just this:

```
from datetime import datetime

lst = '20180101,20180102'

# first convert to datetime
lst = [datetime.strptime(i, '%Y%M%d') for i in lst.split(',')]

# define year combiner
def year_range(lst, year_start, year_end):
    return [i.replace(year=j) for j in range(year_start, year_end+1) for i in lst]

# make list for year range from lst
lst = year_range(lst, 2015, 2018)

# [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 1),
#  datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 1),
#  datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 1),
#  datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 1),
#  datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2, 0, 1),
#  datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 0, 1),
#  datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 2, 0, 1),
#  datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 0, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you DO need to use the re module, you just match the sequence of numbers and replace them with what you find intermixed with the hyphens:

```
import re

string = '20180101,20180102,20180103,20180104,20180105,20180106,20180107,20180108,20180109,20180110,20180111,20180112,20180113,20180114,20180115,20180116,20180117,20180118,20180119,20180120,20180121,20180122,20180123,20180124,20180125,20180126,20180127,20180128,20180129,20180130,20180131,20180201,20180202,20180203,20180204,20180205,20180206,20180207,20180208'

result = re.sub('([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})','\\1-\\2-\\3',string,0)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
string = '20180203'
new_string = string[:4:] + '-' + string[4:6:] + '-' + string[6::]
print (new_string)
```

Result:

> 2018-02-03

Just make sure that the date is in the format YYYYMMDD.